# How to change an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I want to change the value of an XSD attribute `@type` from `xsd:boolean` to `xsd:string`.

My XSD is

```
<xsd:element name="Complete" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element name="taskno" nillable="true" type="xsd:integer"/>
```

The XSLT what I have written replaces all `@type` attribute values to `xsd:string`.  I am unable to check if the `@type` is `xsd:boolean`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="pNewType" select="'xsd:string'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@type">
        <!-- <xsl:if test="type='xsd:boolean'">
        Found element!!*********
        </xsl:if>     --> *** Condition to check if its boolean doesn't work
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pNewType"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="@type">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="@type[ . = 'xsd:boolean']">
```

**Full XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@type[ . = 'xsd:boolean']">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
      <xsl:value-of select="'xsd:string'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```